After updating VS2019 to VS2022 : Method not found: 'Void Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.PublishRequest.set_MessageGroupId(System.String)'
Our service was working properly in VS 2019, but when we tried to execute locally in VS2022. We start getting the below exception:

Method not found: Void Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.PublishRequest.set_MessageGroupId(System.String).

Our service have the target framework version was .NET Core 3.1 we tried with upgraded target version and installed other SDKs on local machine like 3.1.426 ,6.0.421, and 8.0.204
But did not get any luck.
how can we solve this issue?

If your code worked without issues in Visual Studio 2019 but problems arise after updating to Visual Studio 2022 without any changes to the code, then the issue may lie not with the SDK version but with the compatibility of Visual Studio 2022. Ensure that your project's configuration in Visual Studio 2022 matches that of Visual Studio 2019. For instance, verify that the target framework version, compilation options, and other settings remain consistent.
